How do I subscribe profiles using the Klaviyo api?
I'm trying to subscribe and unsubscribe profiles in Klaviyo using their api. Unsubscribe works, subscribe does not.
This post is accepted, but why is does Klaviyo still say the profile has "Never Subscribed".
  "type": "profile-subscription-bulk-create-job",
  "attributes": {
    "custom_source": "Marketing Event",
    "profiles": {
      "data": [
        {
          "type": "profile",
          "id": "1234567890",
          "attributes": {
            "email": "test@live.com",
            "subscriptions": {
              "email": {
                "marketing": {
                  "consent": "SUBSCRIBED"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


From the documentation:

If the provided list has double opt-in enabled, profiles will receive
a message requiring their confirmation before subscribing. Otherwise,
profiles will be immediately subscribed without receiving a
confirmation message.

Normally, the most common issue is to see if your List's consent setting is double optin or single optin.  If it's double optin, then a Profile is not subscribed until the user confirms their subscription (from an automated email sent to them).
Since you didn't specify a List, then double check your account's default opt-in settings here: https://www.klaviyo.com/settings/account/api-keys

Thanks this was correct. You must have single opt it and a list.
